# How to extract data from map[string]interface{}?

Tags: go

I am sending the data to the API like following:

```
{"after": {"amount": 811,"id":123,"status":"Hi"}, "key": [70]}
```

and  i am getting following while printing :

```
 map[after:map[amount:811 id:123 status:Hi ] key:[70]]
```

Is there any way to print individual field like this??
**amount::800
id:123
status:Hi**

The code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

var (
    PORT       = ":8080"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("In Main")
    http.HandleFunc("/", changedData)
    http.ListenAndServe(PORT, nil)
}

type Data struct {
    Id               int64 `json:"id"`
    Amount           float64 `json:"amount"`
    Status           string  `json:"status"`
    
}


type mark map[string]interface{}

func changedData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Coming From API")
    
    reqBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    fmt.Println("Data coming from API ", string(reqBody))

    digit := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(string(reqBody)))

    for digit.More() {
        var result mark
        err := digit.Decode(&result)
        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            break
        }
        fmt.Println("final_data ", result)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can define a `struct type` if you know the JSON file format or if the JSON format is predefined. As far as I know that mostly using `interface{}` is a way when you don't know the JSON format or there is no predefined format of the JSON. If you define a `struct type`  and use it while unmarshaling the JSON to struct, you can access the variables by typing like `data.Id` or `data.Status`.

Here's an example code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Data struct {
    AfterData After `json:"after"`
    Key       []int `json:"key"`
}

type After struct {
    Id     int64   `json:"id"`
    Amount float64 `json:"amount"`
    Status string  `json:"status"`
}

func main() {
    j := []byte(`{"after": {"amount": 811,"id":123,"status":"Hi"}, "key": [70]}`)
    var data *Data
    err := json.Unmarshal(j, &data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(data.AfterData)
    fmt.Println(data.AfterData.Id)
    fmt.Println(data.AfterData.Amount)
    fmt.Println(data.AfterData.Status)

}
```

Output will be

```
{123 811 Hi}
123
811
Hi
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ozG-wNrL1jj)

Answer (score 2):

Decode to a Go type that matches the structure of the JSON document.  You declared a type for the "after" field. Wrap that type with a struct to match the document.

```
func changedData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var v struct{ After Data }
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&v)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "bad request", 400)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("final_data: %#v", v.After)
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/_ktwpb5hAIw).